# keyword search volumn and google pagerank

Tags: api, pagerank

how do I find a keyword's search volume/popularity?
how do I find a site's pagerank?
Is google API one way to do it?  are there other ways?

Answer (score 0):

For checking a search term's popularity (relatively), you can use Google Trends:

http://www.google.com/trends

For checking a site's page rank, there's this site:

http://www.prchecker.info/check_page_rank.php

Comment: thanks! I'm more interested to see prchecker actually go about finding the page rank.  Also how do I get how many searches a particular keyword fetches/month on google?  A lot of seo tools are getting these info, how do they actually find them?

Answer (score 0):

To get searches: https://adwords.google.com/select/KeywordToolExternal

to get pagerank, install the google toolbar ore use googles API for which you need a key